# Why vim creates an extra last line when importing a template?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, gvim, neovim-qt

My init.vim code:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.cpp 0r C:\Users\User\Desktop\cp\Template.cpp
```

When i create a `.cpp` file, `Template.cpp` code is imported in that cpp file. 
upto this point, everything is fine.

but while doing that, **vim always leaves a last blank line** (which i don't want)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    // code goes here
}
-- unwanted last line --
```

So can anyone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:r` *inserts* the contents of a file. It does not overwrite existing contents. Since a new file opened in Vim can't have *zero* lines<sup>*</sup> you'll be adding the file's contents to one blank line.

Simplest thing to do is just add an additional command to your autocommand:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.cpp 0r C:\Users\User\Desktop\cp\Template.cpp | $d
```

So we use `|` to indicate an additional command and `:d[elete]` with a "range" of `$` (last line).

Or, if you'd prefer to start with the cursor at the beginning of the buffer:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.cpp r C:\Users\User\Desktop\cp\Template.cpp | 1d
```

<sub>** According to various definitions/specifications (including [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file#Unix_text_files)) a "text file" must contain at a minimum a terminating line feed character. IOW, totally empty files are not considered text files and Vim is a text file editor...*</sub>